# Probability of match in rank choice problem for DC schools

Tags: probability

Our area has a rank choice system for school assignment. I am trying to figure out the probability of being accepted to any school on my list based on the odds of acceptance at any one school. Each schools odds of acceptance is independent of the other. I am hoping to find a generalized solution that is based on the individual odds of being accepted at any given school, and the number of schools chosen for my list. For instance I might only list 2 schools, or to increase my odds I could add 10 schools to my list. Pretend I have the odds of admissions for a N schools:

```
Name          Odds
School 1       7/10
School 2       2/10
...             ...
School N       n/10
```

What is the probability of being accepted to at least one (order doesn't matter) school? How does that change if I list 3 schools vs N schools (where only listed schools are considered possibilities)?

After spending too much time, I suspect I have the answer, although I would love to have someone confirm it. Here is what I have:

$\sum_{i=1}^N P_i-\prod_{i=1}^N P_i$

Where P is the probability of acceptance into school i, and N is the number of schools included in the list.

Comment: A search for "deferred assignment algorithm" doesn't bring up any obvious candidates. If something can't be assumed known and isn't immediately obvious from search results, it should be defined in the question in order to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that you don't get accepted by any school is:

$$\prod_\limits{k=1}^{N} \left(1-P_k\right)$$

The probability that you get accepted by **at least one** school is the probability of all final outcomes minus the probability that you get accepted by none, which is the only outcome that fails the criteria.

The probability of all final outcomes equals $1$, so the answer is:

$$1-\prod_\limits{k=1}^{N} \left(1-P_k\right)$$